# Clipping in sankeyPlot in RStudio output

Tags: r, rstudio, rcharts

I was experimenting with making sankeyPlots in RStudio using the code below.

```
rm(list = ls())
require(reshape)
require(rCharts)
require(rjson)
target <- c('TMF', 'TMF', 'TMF','Evaporation','Mill Reclaim','Void Losses','Seepage')
source <- c('Precipitation & Run Off','Slurry','Other','TMF','TMF','TMF','TMF')
value <- c(638,1610,755,118,1430,466,2)
x <- data.frame(target,source,value)
sankeyPlot <- rCharts$new()
sankeyPlot$set(
data = x,
nodeWidth = 10,
nodePadding = 10,
layout = 32,
width = 1100,
height = 675,
units = "cubic metres",
title = "Sankey Diagram"
)
sankeyPlot$setLib('http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey')
sankeyPlot
```

But when I view the output of the sankeyPlot, the right and bottom edges of the sankeyPlot are hidden behind some kind of white margin or limit or something which means that the right most nodes look like they're partially drawn.  But they're there, because you can drag them out and see the thing again.

Is there a better way to print/save/publish a sankeyPlot from this code so that it's ready for a presentation?

Answer (score 0):

Change the width and height like so that it covers the whole area

```
sankeyPlot$set(
  data = df,
  nodeWidth = 15,
  nodePadding = 10,
  layout = 32,
  width = 2000,
  height = 5000
)
```